# How to add background image behind container

Tags: html, css

So i am currently working on a small assignment we have in school as practice but i don't know how to add a background image behind container. Here is a example i found quickly of what i want to achieve, note the background image http://www.njuskalo.hr. I tried adding a background image to body but that doesn't work either. Also i made two new div tags (.left and .right) to try and add it on the sides of container, also didn't work.
Here is my code: http://textuploader.com/d5j5d
Also note that i changed and erased a lot of stuff trying other things. And please go easy i know the code is a mess but it's something i am doing at the last minute so feel free to point out all the mistakes.

Comment: Ok i feel like an idiot now... The problem was in my file name. I went back to my css and added .jpg to my file name in body's background-image. And the image appeared...

Comment: you cannot add background in front of container. LOL

Comment: Voting to Close as this question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 5):

A background image is done like this:

```
.container {
  background-image: url("../images/backgroundImageLocation.jpg");
}
```

```css
body{
  background-image: url("http://image.flaticon.com/teams/1-freepik.jpg");
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-size: 50px;
  }
.container {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: pink;
}
.left {
  position: absolute;
  left: -100px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
.right {
  position: absolute;
  right: -100px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Can be used with background:

```
    body, html {
        background: url("../YOUR_IMAGE_PATH/image.jpg") no-repeat fixed center center;
    }
```

**no-repeat** will not repeat the background, **fixed** will fix the background when scolling and 
 **center center** will center your image to the page.

and with background-image:

```
body, html {
        background-image: url("../YOUR_IMAGE_PATH/image.jpg")
    }
```